# Finding the differential equation by the given complete primitive

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find a differential equation by the given complete primitive $y = (cx+\log(x)+1)^{-1}$ and $c$ being the arbitrary constant

So, I did the differentiated the complete primitive

which I got $y' = -(c+\frac{1}{x})(cx+\log(x)+1)^{-2}$ and right now I am stuck what to do next and how to reach the answer.

Answer for this exercise is : $(y\log(x)-1)y = y'x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given solution formula, we have
$$
c= \frac1{xy}-\frac{\log x}{x}-\frac1{x}.
$$
Differentiating both parts, we obtain
$$
0=-\frac{xy'+y}{x^2y^2}-\frac{1-\log x}{x^2}+\frac1{x^2}.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $x^2y^2$, we get
$$
0=-xy'-y-y^2+y^2\log x+y^2
$$
$$
xy'=-y+y^2\log x
$$
$$
xy'=y(y\log x-1).
$$